# Limit apt repo to a certain arch?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, software-sources

I have several repositories that don't have armhf binaries (for RPi cross-compiler), so `apt-get` always gives me a ton of 404 errors on updating package lists. It also prevents me from running `do-release-upgrade` as it can't find armhf compiled system binaries, that it doesn't need and can't run anyways.

I'm looking for a way to tell it to only search for specific arches in certain repositories so I can fix the massive wall of 404s on `apt-get update`. Google was no help; so as far as I know this isn't a dupe; and the one question that was possibly related was about GPG errors, of which I have none.

sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted i386 amd64
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted amd64 i386

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted amd64 i386
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted amd64 i386

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse i386 amd64
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse i386 amd64
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse i386 amd64
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse i386 amd64

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe i386 amd64
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse i386 amd64
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse i386 amd64

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main amd64 i386
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main i386 amd64

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse amd64 i386
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse i386 amd64


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main amd64 i386
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu trusty main amd64 i386
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu trusty main amd64 i386
## Depôt MultiSystem
deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main amd64 i386
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu trusty main amd64
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu karmic main amd64
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon/ubuntu karmic main amd64
deb http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/ trusty main amd64 i386
deb-src http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/ trusty main amd64 i386


#Raspberry Pi APT for cross-compiler
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi armhf
```

Output of `apt-get update`:

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://liveusb.info all InRelease                                          
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty InRelease                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease [14.9 kB]            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release.gpg                                        
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty Release                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release                                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://liveusb.info all/main amd64 Packages                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]    
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex    
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [933 B]          
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic InRelease                        
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                  
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic InRelease                                  
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [62.0 kB]      
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi armhf Packages/DiffIndex    
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [62.0 kB]              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release.gpg                                
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release [62.0 kB]            
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [143 kB]          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release                                    
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [1,408 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release                                    
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [52.8 kB]        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                              
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [17.4 kB]    
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US            
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [4,060 B]      
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en              
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [17.3 kB]  
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,883 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [15.3 kB]          
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages              
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages          
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages          
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi armhf Packages              
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi amd64 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/amd64 amd64 Packages                      
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main armhf Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/armhf amd64 Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/armhf armhf Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/amd64 armhf Packages                      
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib i386 Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/amd64 i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/amd64 Translation-en_US                    
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/main Sources                                
  404  Not Found
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/armhf i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 Sources                                
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/armhf Translation-en_US          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/amd64 Translation-en                      
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 Sources                                
  404  Not Found
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/armhf Translation-en            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en_US        
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 amd64 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/main armhf Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en          
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 armhf Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US          
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 armhf Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en              
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/main i386 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 i386 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_US      
Err http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 i386 Packages                          
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en          
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/amd64 Translation-en                        
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en_US            
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en              
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/i386 Translation-en                          
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                      
Ign http://files.avast.com trusty/main Translation-en                          
Fetched 457 kB in 15s (29.7 kB/s)                                              
W: GPG error: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9165938D90FDDD2E
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/dists/all/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/armhf/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/armhf/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/rpi/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/armhf/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'i386/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/amd64/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/i386/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/i386/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/i386/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/dists/trusty/i386/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'i386/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'i386/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/karmic/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon/ubuntu/dists/karmic/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'amd64/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wii.sceners.linux/wiithon-1.1/ubuntu/dists/trusty/amd64/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

dkpg arches: i386, amd64, armhf

I'm using an ARM cross compiler as Raspberry Pi is very slow to compile larger things, and crashes on some huge ones, even with a 4GB swapfile on an external drive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [`man sources.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sources.list):

```
The format for a sources.list entry using the deb and deb-src types is:

   deb [ options ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
... 
options is always optional and needs to be surrounded by square
brackets. It can consist of multiple settings in the form
setting=value. Multiple settings are separated by spaces. The following
settings are supported by APT (note however that unsupported settings
will be ignored silently):

·   arch=arch1,arch2,...  can be used to specify for which
    architectures information should be downloaded. If this option is
    not set all architectures defined by the APT::Architectures option
    will be downloaded. 

·   arch+=arch1,arch2,...  and arch-=arch1,arch2,...  which can be used
    to add/remove architectures from the set which will be downloaded.       
...
The first line gets package information for the architectures in
APT::Architectures while the second always retrieves amd64 and armel.

       deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main
       deb [ arch=amd64,armel ] http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

So try something like:

```
deb [ arch=armhf ] http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi armhf
```

Comment: blah, URI parse error, will try sticking it after the source

Comment: nope, didn't work, still searching for amd64 in the RPi source.
derp, didn't notice that options need o be included in brackets

Comment: it works if arch=* is enclosed in brackets, will mark as accepted if the answer is changed to reflect that ([arch=armhf] works)

Comment: @user256130 Indeed you're correct. There are examples further down the manpage which show that's the correct syntax. UPdated.

Comment: The [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/sources.list) url.