# Testing an APT repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, raspberrypi, testing

I am trying to setup a distribution mechanism for Raspbian (Raspberry Pi) on a Ubuntu server. I have read most of the posts here and articles I could find about setting up an APT repo. I don't know if it works (I am pretty sure it does not as I get an error on the RPi side)... Debugging is not obvious.

Here are my questions / issues:

1. I need packages. I have not done one by myself yet. I found some chromium packages and try to install them via mini-dinstall. It would be great to "see" something but they are still in the incoming directory. Having a complete directory structure would be useful. Where can I find a set of packages (let's say 2-3) that are not in the main repositories (kind of the hello world of package)?
2. If I am not mistaken, the server itself is just a plain ol' Apache, which we all love. Right? No modules? Mine is here: (do you see anything wrong?)

   ```
   http://packator0.makenator.com/archive
   ```
3. The webserver should also distribute your GPG public key, right? Mine is here.

   ```
   http://packator0.makenator.com/archive/makenator-archive-keyring/makenator-archive-keyring.gpg
   ```
4. The client should have a list of repo:

   ```
   deb http:// packator0.makenator.com/archive stable/all/
   deb http:// packator0.makenator.com/archive unstable/all/
   ```
5. The client should learn about the public key:

   ```
   gpg --keyserver http:// packator0.makenator.com/archive/makenator-archive-keyring/makenator-archive-keyring.gpg --recv 1EFBD9A7AEA2C37C
   ```

   but I get:

   ```
   gpg: requesting key AEA2C37C from http server packator0.makenator.com
   gpg: /home/pi/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
   gpg: key AEA2C37C: public key "[information is ok, just removed it here]" imported
   gpg: key 1BCD4B6B: rejected by import filter
   gpg: Total number processed: 2
   gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
   ```
6. And of course, when I run apt-get update on the RPi, I get (error is on the last line):

   ```
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ InRelease                                  
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ InRelease                                
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ Release.gpg                                                                          
   ...
   Get:1 http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Release.gpg [287 B]  
   Hit http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ Release                                         
   Hit http:// archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages                                  
   Hit http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Release                                                      
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Release                                                                           
   Hit http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ Packages                                                                            
   ...
   Hit http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Packages                                                  
   ...
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ Translation-en_US                         
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com stable/all/ Translation-en                            
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Translation-en_US                       
   Ign http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Translation-en                          
   ...
   Fetched 287 B in 6s (42 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   Reading package lists... Done
   W: GPG error: http:// packator0.makenator.com unstable/all/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1EFBD9A7AEA2C37C
   ```

Thanks for your help. Partial answers are really good too!

(because I am new here, I could not post too many links, hence the space in the URL)

Comment: `gpg --keyserver  ...` is adding the key to your personal keyring. You should add to apt, instead. IIRC the command is [`add-apt-key`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/add-apt-key.8.html). The source field should look like: `deb http:// packator0.makenator.com/archive stable`, architecture is specified as an option, if it has to be specified *at all*: http://askubuntu.com/q/554079/158442

Comment: Thanks @muru, this helped discover an issue I had with my keys. Continuing on the rest ;)